# Javascript telnet connection without nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

is it possible to create a telnet connection without using node.js? I want to try to communicate with a Teamspeak3 telnet console. I don´t want use node.js cause some guys can´t install it correctly.

It´s for a open source project :).

Comment: i don't think you can without nodejs. You will need nodejs to be used as a proxy

Comment: Use anything else? It's not clear what you're asking-you can create connections using anything that supports networking.

Comment: Do you want to use telnet with a browser?

Comment: I use currently php (http://ts3admin.info/) to manage the teamspeak server. But with php I need to create always a new connection and close her. It would be nice if I could make a connection and hold them for the whole time the user is on the web page.